# Make Flask listen for realtime updates in my Firestore tree

Tags: python, firebase, flask, socket.io, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get Flask to listen for realtime updates in my Firestore tree.

I have found this code snippet in the documentation at this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen):

```
# Create a callback on_snapshot function to capture changes
def on_snapshot(doc_snapshot, changes, read_time):
    for doc in doc_snapshot:
        print(u'Received document snapshot: {}'.format(doc.id))

doc_ref = db.collection(u'cities').document(u'SF')

# Watch the document
doc_watch = doc_ref.on_snapshot(on_snapshot)
```

But I'm not sure how I should use it in Flask.

Basically what I want to is to let Flask listen for changes in a document in Firestore and then send those changes to my frontend application (Reactjs). I have been looking at Flask-SocketIO which seems to be what I need, but I'm not sure.

Could someone help me?

**Edit**

I'm trying do like this:

```
# Create a callback on_snapshot function to capture changes
def on_snapshot(doc_snapshot, changes, read_time):
    for doc in doc_snapshot:
        flask_print("Received document snapshot: {}".format(doc.id))
        flask_print("snapshot was recieved from firebase!")
        emit("snapshot", {"data": doc.id})


@socketio.on("snapshot")
def snapshot_to_ferontend(snapshot):
    flask_print("snapshot was sent to frontend!")
    send(snapshot)


class SubscribeToGameById(Resource):
    def __init__(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument("game_id", required=True)
        self.args = parser.parse_args()

    def put(self):
        doc_ref = db.collection("games").document(self.args["game_id"])
        doc_ref.on_snapshot(on_snapshot)
```

But I get an error saying: *"RuntimeError: Working outside of request context."*

Comment: You're on the right track. You do need a websocket library like `flask-socketio` to establish a websocket connection between your Flask server and your React frontend. Can you share some of your Flask app code?

Comment: Thank @prithajnath. I have added some code now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library `flask-boiler` to serve the content. Implement `notify` method in your view model mediator `GameViewMediator` like this:

```
class GameViewMediator(ViewMediatorDAV):

    def notify(obj):
        send(obj.to_dict())
```

and bind your view model `GameView` to the domain model `Game`:

```
game_view = GameView()
game_view.bind_to(key="game", obj_type=Game, doc_id="game_id")
game_view.register_listener()
```

You should see the websocket emitting a snapshot of the game with every change.